# Is it functionally fine to hide deprecated error in CakePhp?

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I am developing a mini cms project by using CakePHP 3.x (3.10.4)

I used such an old version of CakePHP due to the server PHP version restriction.

I am totally fine when developing in my local device xampp server, however, when I start to deploy the applications to the production server and configure all the requirements (like the database, migrations, etc), I found an error in one of my page, showing:

```
You are using a deprecated argument order for Cake\Validation\Validator::allowEmptyString. 
You should reverse the order of your `when` and `message` arguments so that they are `message, when`. 
- xxxxxxxxxxx/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Validation/Validator.php, line: 871 
You can disable deprecation warnings by setting `Error.errorLevel` to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` in your config/app.php.
```

Then I do a little research about the problem and found that It should be the bin/bake problem (Please let me know if I was wrong), so I just change the Error.errorLevel to `E_ALL & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED` as suggested in the error message and the problem is gone.

I have two questions:

1. I know it is always not a good practice, but it is totally fine to hide the deprecated warnings (or errors) in such a way in terms of functionality? Would it be some hidden concerns?
2. Why this deprecated warning is not shown in my local device environment, but on the production xampp server?

My project needs to be deployed soon, hope someone could answer my questions, Big Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have different PHP versions.

Comment: More likely different versions of the cakephp framework, since that is where the deprecation warning comes from.

Comment: You certainly can suppress that warning, things will work without an issue. But there is a reason for the warning. Usually the reason is that the deprecated function (or here function signature) will get removed in one of the coming versions. The issue if you now suppress that warning: you will most likely forget about it, fail to deal with it which will result in a very surprised you when things suddenly start _not_ to work any more.

Comment: But there is another thing you need to learn: it seems you have configured your environment to display errors right in the Web UI. That is sometimes fine for a development environment (I still would clearly advise against it), but _never_ for a staging or even production environment. Errors and warnings belong into the log files. Where they don't disturb your UI and can be evaluated and handled.

Comment: Given that it's so simple these days to get hosting for different PHP versions, you're probably better off finding a better host than to stick old versions of software.

Comment: I finally found out that I baked the wrong database migration which made some missing fields for a model. After I re-bake the correct migration and the warning is gone. Thank you for all of you and at least I know such deprecated warnings won't affect the functionality but requires further consideration in the future.

Comment: Evert, Thank you for your suggestion. I know we should consider a better/newer hosting technology such as docker or cloud hosting that could overcome PHP version problems, however, due to the fact that the server is not controlled by myself in this project, I have to stick with such old fashion hosting.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's `functionally` fine to hide deprecated errors. I am doing that on a legacy CakePHP 2.x project that runs on PHP 7.4. They are just warnings that in future versions the functionality will be removed (it's not affecting the existing functionality).

Regarding the second question, it's probably because you have different settings/PHP versions/framework versions.

Comment: Thank you, at least we know that it is functionally fine!